# Open folder issue

Tags: c#, directory

I want to open the folder where a file had been just saved and select the file, for that I use this little code:

```
 var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("Explorer.exe", "/select," + dlg.FileName);
                Process.Start(psi);
```

It works perfectly.

I need to put this code in several places so I decided to create a method, there is also a condition in this method:

```
 private static void OpenFolderAndSelectMyFile(string fileName)
 {
     if (MySettings.Default.openFolder == true)
     {
         var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("Explorer.exe", "/select," + fileName);
         psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
         Process.Start(psi);
     }    
 }
```

This doesn't work as expected: this opens the parent folder (of the folder containing my file). It also selects the folder.

Why this difference in behavior and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked the `filename` being passed in?

Comment: Can you post the calling code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way for this to occur, is `fileName` isn't what it was in your original code. The code is exactly the same, and would work as expected, if `fileName` was in fact what it was in the original code location.

It's likely that `fileName` is now actually the full path to the folder rather than the full path to the file *including the file name.*

Comment: You're right, I was passing a string that had been modified. Now it works properly.